# Meteor ignoring 'selected' attribute on <option> on <select multi>

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, selectize.js, spacebars

I am trying to use a multi select box in meteor and have some of the options be marked with `selected` based on info from the db for use with slectize.js. however it seems like meteor when building its DOM tree ignores the `selected` property.

```
<label>User</label>
<select id="customer_user_id" name="user_id" class="form-control input-sm" multiple>
  {{#each users}}
   {{#if inList _id ../customer_user_id}}
     <option value="{{_id}}" selected>{{full_name}}</option>
     {{else}}
     <option value="{{_id}}">{{full_name}}</option>
     {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

and the helper

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("inList", function (val, list) {
 console.log(list.indexOf(val) > -1)
 console.log(list)
 console.log(val)
return list.indexOf(val) > -1;

});
```

i see that the condition is true but there is no options with the `selected` property

I have been breaking my head on this for more then 24 hours now

I have also tried this method with the same result

```
<label>User</label>
<select id="customer_user_id" name="user_id" class="form-control input-sm" multiple>
  {{#each users}}
  <option value="{{_id}}" {{selected _id ../customer_user_id "selected"}}>{{full_name}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

with this helper

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("selected", function (val1, val2, string) {   
 if (val1 === val2) {
    return string;
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `selected="selected"` instead of just `selected`:

```
<option value="{{_id}}" selected="selected">{{full_name}}</option>
```